# For loops to Create datasets in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to create several datasets via for loop.
basically I want create 29 datasets in which I can find in the 1st one the 44th and 45th column of the DF, in the 2nd one the 46th and 47th column of the DF and so on.
I tried like this with no results.

```
data. <- data.frame(matrix( nrow=1442, ncol=2))

for (i in 1:29){
  assign(paste("data",i, sep="_"), data.)
  data_[i][,1] <- DF[,c(43+i)]
  data_[i][,2] <- DF[,c(44+i)]
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: `data_list <- lapply(1:29, function(i) data.frame(X1 = DF[[43+i]], X2 = DF[[44+i]]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution using `purrr`

```r
DF <- data.frame(matrix(runif(10000),ncol=100))

library(purrr)

res <- 0:28 %>% 
  # create the indices to subset
  map( ~ c(44, 45) + .x) %>%
  # subset the df for each indice group
  map( ~ DF[, .x])

length(res)
#> [1] 29
str(head(res))
#> List of 6
#>  $ :'data.frame':    100 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ X44: num [1:100] 0.477 0.0593 0.2616 0.7349 0.1202 ...
#>   ..$ X45: num [1:100] 0.43 0.105 0.557 0.341 0.111 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    100 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ X45: num [1:100] 0.43 0.105 0.557 0.341 0.111 ...
#>   ..$ X46: num [1:100] 0.78 0.877 0.518 0.162 0.565 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    100 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ X46: num [1:100] 0.78 0.877 0.518 0.162 0.565 ...
#>   ..$ X47: num [1:100] 0.931 0.985 0.59 0.656 0.713 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    100 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ X47: num [1:100] 0.931 0.985 0.59 0.656 0.713 ...
#>   ..$ X48: num [1:100] 0.82 0.899 0.359 0.809 0.329 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    100 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ X48: num [1:100] 0.82 0.899 0.359 0.809 0.329 ...
#>   ..$ X49: num [1:100] 0.7982 0.0966 0.2716 0.3364 0.7295 ...
#>  $ :'data.frame':    100 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ X49: num [1:100] 0.7982 0.0966 0.2716 0.3364 0.7295 ...
#>   ..$ X50: num [1:100] 0.83057 0.64207 0.94392 0.00904 0.26966 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
data <- list()

DF <- data.frame(matrix(runif(10000),ncol=100))

for (i in 1:29){
  data[[i]] <- data.frame(DF[,c(43:44+i)])
}

str(data, list.len = 3)
```

Comment: In `c(43:44+i)` you don't need the call to `c()`. But the question is answered, upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
n = 1000
k = 120 
DF = matrix(runif(n*k), n, k)

for (i in 1:29){
    tmp = DF[,c(43, 43) + c(2*i-1, 2*i)]
    assign(paste0("data_", i), tmp)
    }   

ls()
all(data_1 == DF[,c(44, 45)])
all(data_2 == DF[,c(46, 47)])
```

Doing `data_[i]` will make R look for the object called `data_`, so you can't just subscript the object name like that.